# How to show $s(t)=\frac{f(x+tp)-f(x)}{t}$ is monotonically increasing?

Tags: analysis

How to show that:

$$s(t)=\frac{f(x+tp)-f(x)}{t}$$

is monotonically increasing,

$f(x)$ is convex and for all $t\in(0,1]$.

Attempt:
I used convexity, and came with,

$\frac{f(x+t(\bar x -x))}{t}\le f(\bar x)- f(x)$ by convexity. From here I tried many things, but could n't finalized.Could you please help.

Comment: Which definition of convexity do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x < y \leq z$. Then $\lambda = (y-x)/(z-x) \in [0,1]$ with
$$
 (1-\lambda)x + \lambda z
 = x + \lambda (z-x)
 = x + (y-x)
 = y.
$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
 \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}
 &= \frac{f((1-\lambda)x + \lambda z)-f(x)}{y-x} 
 \leq \frac{(1-\lambda)f(x) + \lambda f(z) - f(x)}{y-x} \\
 &= \lambda \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{y-x}
 = \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}.
\end{align*}